# How to set focus on the last character of EditText on Android

Tags: java, android

I need to focus on the last character of EditText by coding way. I know that there is `EditText.requestFocus`, but it set focus on the first character. I'm using java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the call to `requestFocus()`, you can set the position of the cursor at the end of the EditText as follows:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textId);
int pos = editText.getText().length();
editText.setSelection(pos);
```

Comment: I need both of requestFocus and setSelection?

Comment: Yes indeed, call to requestFocus() is needed first to set the focus on your EditText

Answer (score 0):

you can set position of cursor using java

```
editText.setSelection(position)
```

Here position is the index.